# How do i find out possessive expressions and what they link?

Tags: java, opennlp

I'm using opennlp for a small project and I wanted to know if there is a way to find out possessive expressions, the owner and what they own. For example, if i ask "A user should have an email", then I want to get the relationship pair "user", "email".

The approach I can think of now is to get the POS tags (using POSTagger), find out if there are tags that indicate possession and get the nouns that they link by going backward and forward in the POS tag output to get the two entities that the tag relates to.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: no. The longer answer involves understanding how human language works. There are tons of ways to describe a possessive relationship: "John's book", "John has a book", "the book that John has", even "Bill gave a book to John" (from which you can infer that John has the book). In order to reliably extract this sort of relationship, you need to account for all the variations in, e.g., part of speech sequences, vocabulary, non-local relationships ("the book that I'm pretty sure John has"), etc., as well has having access to semantic knowledge (such as knowing that if you give a book to someone, that means they have it). People have spent their entire careers trying to solve problems like this; the most successful approaches so far are only partially successful.

A book such as this may give you a better idea of why this is really, really hard:

[http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Linguistics-Introduction-Language-Processing/dp/0521310385](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521310385)

Or Google "introduction to linguistics" or "introduction to natural language processing".